# redux flow is giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on React/Redux app, I have made reducers to update and delete user profile address, I have to pass error message and success message from these reducers to the components, I am creating const which has success message,

The success message is working fine when I am using in **updateAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess**, but if used success message in 
**updateAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess** as well, than it is giving error in console and my code is not compiling, Can anyone help how to solve this issue, my code and error is displayed below, Thanks in advance

```
// @flow
import { createReducer } from 'reduxsauce';
import I18n from '../i18n/I18n';
import Types from '../actions/Types';

// Init State
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    addresses: null,
    errorMessage: null,
    successMessage: null,
    isLoading: false,
};

/* Generic error message */
const genericError = I18n.getText('error.generic', {}, 'Something went wrong');

/* Update an address */
export const updateAddressByBuyerIdAddressId = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: true,
    successMessage: null,
    errorMessage: null,
});

export const updateAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => {
    const successMessage = I18n.getText('account.address-updated', {}, 'Address updated!');
    return {
        ...state,
        address: action.address,
        successMessage: successMessage,
    };
};

export const updateAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdFailure = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => ({
    ...state,
    errorMessage: action.errorMessage || genericError,
    isLoading: false,
});

/* Deleting an address */
export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressId = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE) => ({
    ...state,
    isLoading: true,
    successMessage: null,
    errorMessage: null,
});

export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => ({
     const successMessage = I18n.getText('account.address-deleted', {}, 'Address deleted!');
     return {
        ...state,
        address: action.address,
        successMessage: successMessage,
      }
});

export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdFailure = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => ({
    ...state,
    errorMessage: action.errorMessage,
    isLoading: false,
});

export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, ACTION_HANDLERS);
```

**Error screen**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `()` brackets from `deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess`. Convert this

```
export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => ({
     const successMessage = I18n.getText('account.address-deleted', {}, 'Address deleted!');
     return {
        ...state,
        address: action.address,
        successMessage: successMessage,
      }
});
```

to this

```
export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => {
     const successMessage = I18n.getText('account.address-deleted', {}, 'Address deleted!');
     return {
        ...state,
        address: action.address,
        successMessage: successMessage,
      }
};
```

As added in the comment the round brackets like `()` auto return and do not require the keyword return but in your case you would like to set a `const` before returning so you are considering it as function so only the curly brackets {} are used.

Comment: A bit of explanation, the round brackets like `()` auto return and do not require the keyword `return` but in your case you would like to set a `const` before returning so only the curly brackets `{}` are used.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping the function block's curly brackets in parenthesis, which should be used to **implicitly** return an object (without the `return` keyword).  Since the function in question includes the `return` keyword, the leading parenthesis wrapping the brackets are unnecessary.

Removing the parenthesis as shown below should resolve the error:

```
export const deleteAddressByBuyerIdAddressIdSuccess = (state: Object = INITIAL_STATE, action: Object) => {
     const successMessage = I18n.getText('account.address-deleted', {}, 'Address deleted!');
     return {
        ...state,
        address: action.address,
        successMessage: successMessage,
      }
};
```